# What does "register" do in detecron2 for training custom dataset?

Tags: image-classification, detectron, dataset

When I read the "Use Custom Datasets" section on the detectron2 web page, I saw that I needed to register my dataset. The web page says:

> " If you want to use a custom dataset while also reusing detectron2’s
> data loaders, you will need to:
>
> Register your dataset (i.e., tell detectron2 how to obtain your
> dataset).
>
> Optionally, register metadata for your dataset."

What exactly does register do? Is it reliable in terms of the security of data that should be kept confidential? When I use this, is my data uploaded where others can access it? Is there any way to use custom data set without registering?

Comment: Run on your local machine, and the dataset won't go anywhere out.